# Rigging low poly Head

Tags: rigging, bones

[image]

I want to turn my Head with the Head bone. But somehow the Head cannot turn to -180 degrees. Which kinda makes sense but I want my Head to turn 360 degrees. What went wrong?
-Lathano

[image]

Comment: do you mean you have created 2 keyframes, one at 0° and one at 360°? could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=pNXk3Qe1" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/pNXk3Qe1/)

Comment: as Lemon says, you need to remove the neck weight on the head, also, you want your head to rotate 360°, in that case, in the N panel, switch the rotation mode from Quaternion to XYZ Euler, and create 2 keyframes, one at 0°, and later on the timeline, one at 360°. Tell me if that's what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Negative angle values mean rotation in **opposite** direction i.e. **clockwise/counterclockwise**. Hence, -180 deg is back from 180 to 0. A 360 degree rotation doesn't need negative angles.

Answer (score 0):

The helmet is weighted on a group named "DEF-spine.006" and to the "Neck".

You need either to lower these weights or simply remove them.

Localize the issue in weight paint mode then switch to edit mode and click remove under the group list.

[image]